# How do I Set MIME Type for a download link from Mailgun

Tags: python, mailgun

I am using mailgun to send an email to notify users that their requested download for the data has been completed, with a link to download the file, the file is stored on AWS.

`Your data is ready for download <a href="aws-link" download>here</a>`

Something like this.

Is there a way to tell the browser to download the file, instead of opening it in a new tab? I guess it's the problem with MIME type, but how do I set it up

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the file is automatically downloaded if I set the `Content-Type` to `binary/octet-stream` when uploading the file in AWS Bucket.

I was looking into the opposite side of the puzzle.